# Perform some event when php session timeout

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, timeout, onbeforeunload

I tried it with jquery 'onbeforeunload',but failed as jquery doing that action even on refreshing page.
All i want to do is ,perform a db function just before any user close his browser or computer.So that i can know he has logged out.I want to add facebook like functionality "Logged in from other devices" ,with a forcefull logout from other devices.

Comment: if you are saving your session into database then probably  you will not need to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way to catch the on browser close event in JavaScript. You can try web socket and CRON job to achieve your wants.

For web socket, you can get the total connections of specific user, and if the connection becomes 0, it means that the user closed all the pages(window or tab) of your web app. Also, you need to keep in your mind the internet disconnection, by this, you need to use CRON job, this CRON job must run every specific minutes (ex: 15 mins), so that if the user lost a connection for 15 minutes, you must automatically log out that user.

If you don't have rules like user must be disconnected after several minutes of idling, then you can just simply use web socket.

Comment: Yes , In my case when user stay idle for some cases then i have to logged him out . But when any user lost his internet connection for 5 min . At same time user logged in from another device let say his mobile device . I make him logged out , Can this be handled by web socket ,Btw thank you very much i got some answer , i will try now .

Comment: Yes, you just need to put sessionID to your database user table, then whenever the user is logging in, you can check the value of sessionID from DB, if it has value, meaning the user is currently logged in from other device/browser, and also, you can add lastActivity to user table to check its session last activity to determine whether the user is currently active, you can do a lot of checking when regards to user's log details.

Answer (score 1):

in system/libraries/session you will find this line

```
// Is the session current?
if (($session['last_activity'] + $this->sess_expiration) < $this->now)
{
    $this->sess_destroy();
    return FALSE;
}
```

you can do anything in this if.

Comment: but be carefull it is a system library

Comment: I have extended php session lib in codeigniter , because codeigniter session have some problem .

Comment: This can't make the user to log out forcefully and automatically from the other currently logged in device.